# Какой наиболее эффективный способ синхронизировать данные между базой FileMaker и MySql

Tags: mysql, репликация

Имеется база FileMaker из 20 и более таблиц. Кол-во записей в таблицах от 1 до 3 млн.
Нужно для нескольких таблиц регулярно синхронизировать данные с данными в MySql базе.
База MySql развернута на отдельном сервере. Для выполнения запросов в MySQL базе используется язык R.

Рассматриваю такие варианты:
Вариант 1

1. Выгружать данные в csv-файл (средствами FileMaker)
2. Загружать во временную таблицу в MySql (средствами R)
3. Обновлять по связи старые записи (средствами R)
4. Добавлять новые записи (средствами R)

Смущает скорость выгрузки в csv-файл и необходимость кидаться файлами между серверами.

Вариант 2

1. Выбирать данные по ODBC подключению к базе FileMaker (средствами R)
2. Запросом UPDATE ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE одновременно обновлять и добавлять данные  (средствами R)

Смущает стабильность подключения и последствия неожиданной потери связи.

Какие еще варианты стоит рассмотреть?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 3.

1. Выгрузить записи в CSV
2. Переместить файл в место, из которого доступна загрузка средствами MySQL (средствами R)
3. Запустить хранимую процедуру MySQL (средствами R, либо использовать Event procedure), которая импортирует данные (LOAD DATA) во временную таблицу (CREATE TABLE) и затем выполнит обновление (INSERT .. ODKU либо REPLACE)